# Docker based Elastic Beanstalk timeout error connecting to RDS

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, amazon-rds, elastic-beanstalk, aws-cli

Hope everyone is doing amazingly great just like me until last day.

Case Story:

1 I have a laravel(php) based admin panel.

2 I ran and tested it locally by connecting it to a mysql database.

3 I created a docker file and test all things on dockers as well.
Note: Up-till now the app was connecting to the mysql database which was running on a docker images being pulled.

4 I then created an ECR repository and logged into it, then built, pushed image to the ecr repo.

5 I created an Elastic Beanstalk application and then built a docker based EB environment from the ECR image.

6 I did not upload the .env file due to the security issues but by going into the Elastic Beanstalk's

Configuration -> Software -> and then added the env keys and values to environment variables provided in the console of EB.

7 I then began the deployment and after the never ending time of about 5 minutes my Docker app was up.

8 I opened the EB url and saw the login page.

9 I then created an RDS Db mysql based and gave its credentials in the form of the environment variables to the

Configurations -> software and env variables of the environment that i just deployed.

10 I reran the link and tried to login but after a long long long very long time. It showed me something like this;

**504 Bad Gateway for ningx.... Something heart breaking like this.**

But i noticed that i was logged into the dashboard and hence I checked other routes and they were working fine.

**PROBLEM**
Why does the db takes that long or the login screen takes that long to login to dashboard where as not even taking me in there and just displaying the "504 bad gateway error."

**REQUIRED SOLUTION**
I have somehow figured that may be i could give in .ebextensions config files to extend the timeout if it may solve the issue. In that case how would i refer to the rds thing, because i actually don't know how to do .ebextensions thing but i just know that this might be the possible solution.

Please help me out in this matter.
Any body please :(

Regards,

Comment: Nevermind!!!
No one came to help but still i am leaving the answer for any one who gets stuck at this phase.

Comment: 1 You actually loginto the instance that holds the setup of your application on elastic beanstalk.

2 run (docker ps -a) to get the id or name of the running container.

3 run (docker exec -it "container_name or container process id") bash

4 cd into the /etc/nginx/ on the root directory of the container running inside the ec2 instance of elastic beanstalk.

5 type sudo nano nginx.conf

6 Add the following line anywhere within httpd {} code block:
 proxy_read_timeout 300;

7 type sudo service nginx restart
Rerun the link or url of eb